# Pivot tables: Filtering values using Greater than

Tags: excel

I am trying to create a pivot table to show values greater than 126. From the pivot table fields list, I have tried using the label filter to show only values that are greater than 126. Though applied, the filter does not seem to work.

Please help recommend a way to achieve this?I have attached a picture to add clarity to how I run my filter. Please advise.

[[Excel Spreadsheet replication of problem][1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19HqLUs5eViL2_O9K4qOMZj5pdeu7n3fV)](https://drive.google.com/open?id=19HqLUs5eViL2_O9K4qOMZj5pdeu7n3fV). Please open in excel for pivot table field lists to show.

[image: Problem Showing values greater than 126]

Comment: I noticed you are using a Label filter rather than a Value filter. If you are filtering on numbers you should use the Value filter.

Comment: Yes, I'd tried both methods with relevant values being at the labels or columns pane of the pivot table but it didn't work.

Comment: Please see replication of problem on this EXCEL spreadsheet. Download and open it rather than use the Google Sheet viewer since we need the pivot table field lists to show: https://drive.google.com/open?id=19HqLUs5eViL2_O9K4qOMZj5pdeu7n3fV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded your sheet and there are two potential resolutions. They are both kind of kludgey, but they do what you need. Power Pivot may have functionality to filter values.

First, you can create a helper column that determines if the value meets your criteria. Have the pivot count this helper column, Then exclude the FALSE column from your table. This is probably the approach I'd take.

Or, you can drop the Count on Waiting List in the columns box. Right click on the Column Labels, click Group, in the Grouping dialog - Starting at = 126, By: = 2000. Click OK. Click the down arrow on the counted field in Columns, click Move to Report Filter. Click the down arrow on the filter and exclude <126. You should be left with one column which counts values above or equal to 126 by year.

Excel pivot tables filter on the values in rows and columns in a pivot table, not the value grid. The value grid is filtered by the selections for columns and rows.

It's kind of a kludge, but it does what you need and should accommodate new data assuming your pivot source range gets updated. Excel Tables functionality will adjust your pivot source for you automatically. Format your data as an Excel Table before creating your pivot.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I used your first option and added a TRUE/FALSE Helper column then ran a filter. Easy and works! Thanks